Generalized multinomial coefficient
I would like to as a question about multinomial coefficients. I know that for the binomial coefficient, the generalized version for real numbers looks like this:
$x \choose y$ = $\frac{\Gamma(x+1)}{\Gamma(y+1)\Gamma(x-y+1)}$ where $\Gamma$ is the Gamma function, defined for positive real numbers/complex numbers with positive real parts.
I want to do the same for the multinomial coefficient $x \choose y_1,y_2,...,y_n$ = $\frac{n!}{y_1!y_2!..y_n!}$.
How should I go about it? The first idea for everyone would be to do the same thing as done for the binomial coefficient and it would look like this:
$x \choose y_1,y_2,...,y_n$ = $\frac{\Gamma(x+1)}{\Gamma(y_1+1)\Gamma(y_2+1)...\Gamma(y_n+1)}$
Is this right?

A multinomial coefficient is just a product of binomial coefficients, you can start from that formula and translate it to gamma function or whatever other representation.
